# what is the base for "pod install" command?

Tags: ios, react-native, cocoapods

when `npm install` command runs, It installs all the packages mentioned in the `package.json`.

when `pod install` command is run, which is the base file to install all required pods?

Is there any file in iOS like `package.json` that decides which `pods` have to be installed?

Answer (score 1):

The Podfile itself. It's a ruby file looking something like this:

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
# platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'ProjectName' do
  # Comment the next line if you don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!

  pod 'Alamofire', '5.6.2'

end
```